# Realm sum amount of tableview cell

Tags: swift, realm, func

I have a tableView for user to see transaction of selectedAccount. In my transaction will show amount of the transaction and the balance after the transaction incurred with realm objects. I would expect each cell to have the balance after the transaction showing in UILabel. And I could not figure out what logic is required for this to work out.

```
class Account : Object {

    var ofTransactions = List<Transaction>()
    var direction: Int16 = 0

    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var info : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var balance : String = ""

//MARK: - Transaction Section
class Transaction : Object {
    ///Child of Transaction
    var parentAccount = LinkingObjects(fromType: Account.self, property: "ofTransactions")

    @objc dynamic var categoryType : Category?
    @objc dynamic var amount : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var date : Date?


}
//MARK: - Transaction Category Section
enum CategoryType : Int, CaseIterable {
    case income = 0
    case expense = 1
    case openingBalance = 2

    init?(id : Int) {
        if id < CategoryType.allCases.count {
            self = CategoryType.allCases[id]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}



class Category : Object {
    @objc dynamic var icon : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var categoryTypeID : Int = CategoryType.income.rawValue
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var categoryID : Int = 0
```

```
// Example
tableViewCell At indexpath.
Row 0 Information
CategoryType : Income
Amount : + 1000
Balance : = 1000

Row 1 Information
CategoryType : Expense
Amount : -500
Balance : = 500 (row1 - row0)

Row 2 Information
CategoryType : Expense
Amount : -200
Balance : = 300 (row2 - row1)
```

```
// Outlets

@IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var amountTF: CurrencyField!

   //This is not under realm Object Transaction()
   @IBOutlet weak var balanceLabel: UILabel!
```

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TransactionCell", for: indexPath) as! TransactionTableViewCell
        if let transCell = getTransactions?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.categoryLabel.text = transCell.categoryType?.name
            cell.dateLabel.text = transCell.date?.toMMMdString()


            //Implementation of currency format to amount TextField
            cell.amountTF.text = transCell.amount
            cell.amountTF.locale = Locale(identifier: selectedAccount.currency!.localeId)

      /*
            let indexAccount0 = getTransactions[indexPath.row].amount
            let indexAccount1 = getTransactions[indexPath.row + 1].amount
            print("indexAccount 0 : \(indexAccount0)")
            print("indexAccount 1 : \(indexAccount1)")

            let sum1 = Double(indexAccount0)
            let sum2 = Double(indexAccount1)
            let totalSum = sum1! + sum2!
            print("sum1 : \(sum1)")
            print("sum2 : \(sum2)")

            print("totalsum : \(totalSum)")
            */
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but performing calculations when a tableView cell is being createdis probably not the best plan. Generally speaking, following MVC is a good practice; do calculations within the Controller and then use the View to display them. That's not a strict policy but tableViews are designed to be lightweight and fast and cells can go in and out of scope at the OS's whim. So keep your data in the dataSource so the cells can populate/update whenever they want without affecting anything. Also, if you're having issues with a tableView, including that code would be helpful.

Comment: I had updated my cellForRow At indexPath for this question, however no results really came out and keep having error for performing codes. as I still have no idea how to put the logic using tableView datasources. I been trying to store a new property as `balance:String` in realm's but fail as my cell is filtered by date. which will cause `balance` wont show the correct cell. So the best way would be as you mention, to do calculation on the viewcontroller but I still thinking of a logic behind it

Comment: You need to find a tableView tutorial on the net and also review the MVC design pattern. Those will both help a lot when developing your app and will make it much more maintainable. The other issue is with the question itself - there are function calls in the code that don't indicate what they do. For example `getTransactions`; what does that do? Does it return a number of transactions? Or just one? Can you add a function within the Transaction class that calculates whatever it is you want calculated? Help us to help you by creating a question that's clear, minimal code and the desired output.